# Настройка адаптива сайта

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы сайт до ширины экрана 1200 сужался пропорционально, а меньше 1200 уже работал адаптив

Answer (score 1):

Используйте правило `@media`

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю если есть у Вас в head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` такой тег. Если нет то добавьте. А дальше уже работа с media-queries

```css
.container {
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  
}
@media (max-width: 1200px){
  .container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos nihil, eveniet a cum ex dolorem. Architecto saepe, nulla, ipsum voluptatum maxime nisi porro quia vel deleniti. Aperiam nam, deleniti eos.
  </div>
</div> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Видимо вопрос не так задал)
Есть верстка http://funko-dev.onelowen.beget.tech/, необходимо чтобы до ширины 1200 сужалось все пропорционально. Сейчас это реализовано так <meta name="viewport" content="width=1920">, а с разрешения меньше 1200 с помощью jquery меняется на <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> и начинает работать адаптив.

Но это криво работает. Вопрос: можно ли уменьшать все пропорционально до ширины 1200 пикселей не меняя верстки, т.е не меняя все размеры на *vw?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c851224/v851224552/32993/9YdH-oG4VC4.jpg